# how can i fix this NullExceptionPointer error?

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception, reference

Hey this is ready made code from a Maple Story game
That I run a function for me it works for others does not
They do not get a timer. seems chr.getFitness() returning null
I'm not strong in java I would love if someone would help.
[Error 1 img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGNBt.png)

Also they cant pass last stage in game
[Error 2 img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XP28.png)

MapleFitness Script

```js
/*
    This file is part of the OdinMS Maple Story Server
    Copyright (C) 2008 Patrick Huy <patrick.huy@frz.cc>
               Matthias Butz <matze@odinms.de>
               Jan Christian Meyer <vimes@odinms.de>

    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as
    published by the Free Software Foundation version 3 as published by
    the Free Software Foundation. You may not use, modify or distribute
    this program under any other version of the GNU Affero General Public
    License.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU Affero General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

package server.events.gm;

import client.MapleCharacter;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import server.TimerManager;
import tools.MaplePacketCreator;

/**
 *
 * @author kevintjuh93
 */
public class MapleFitness {
       private MapleCharacter chr;
       private long time = 0;
       private long timeStarted = 0;
       private ScheduledFuture<?> schedule = null;
       private ScheduledFuture<?> schedulemsg = null;
       
       public MapleFitness(final MapleCharacter chr) {
           this.chr = chr;
           this.schedule = TimerManager.getInstance().schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            if (chr.getMapId() >= 109040000 && chr.getMapId() <= 109040004)
                chr.changeMap(chr.getMap().getReturnMap());
            }
           }, 900000);
       }
       
       public void startFitness() {
           chr.getMap().startEvent();
           chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.getClock(900));
           this.timeStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
           this.time = 900000;  
           checkAndMessage();         

           chr.getMap().getPortal("join00").setPortalStatus(true);
           chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "The portal has now opened. Press the up arrow key at the portal to enter."));
       }
       
        public boolean isTimerStarted() {
            return time > 0 && timeStarted > 0;
        }    
    
       public long getTime() {
           return time;
       }

       public void resetTimes() {
           this.time = 0;
           this.timeStarted = 0;
           schedule.cancel(false);
           schedulemsg.cancel(false);
       }

       public long getTimeLeft() {
           return time - (System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStarted);
       }

       public void checkAndMessage() {
           this.schedulemsg = TimerManager.getInstance().register(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (chr.getFitness() == null) {
                    resetTimes();
                }
            if (chr.getMap().getId() >= 109040000 && chr.getMap().getId() <= 109040004) {
             if (getTimeLeft() > 9000 && getTimeLeft() < 11000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "You have 10 sec left. Those of you unable to beat the game, we hope you beat it next time! Great job everyone!! See you later~"));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 99000 && getTimeLeft() < 101000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "Alright, you don't have much time remaining. Please hurry up a little!"));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 239000 && getTimeLeft() < 241000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "The 4th stage is the last one for [The Maple Physical Fitness Test]. Please don't give up at the last minute and try your best. The reward is waiting for you at the very top!"));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 299000 && getTimeLeft() < 301000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "The 3rd stage offers traps where you may see them, but you won't be able to step on them. Please be careful of them as you make your way up."));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 359000 && getTimeLeft() < 361000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "For those who have heavy lags, please make sure to move slowly to avoid falling all the way down because of lags."));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 499000 && getTimeLeft() < 501000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "Please remember that if you die during the event, you'll be eliminated from the game. If you're running out of HP, either take a potion or recover HP first before moving on."));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 599000 && getTimeLeft() < 601000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "The most important thing you'll need to know to avoid the bananas thrown by the monkeys is *Timing* Timing is everything in this!"));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 659000 && getTimeLeft() < 661000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "The 2nd stage offers monkeys throwing bananas. Please make sure to avoid them by moving along at just the right timing."));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 699000 && getTimeLeft() < 701000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "Please remember that if you die during the event, you'll be eliminated from the game. You still have plenty of time left, so either take a potion or recover HP first before moving on."));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 779000 && getTimeLeft() < 781000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "Everyone that clears [The Maple Physical Fitness Test] on time will be given an item, regardless of the order of finish, so just relax, take your time, and clear the 4 stages."));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 839000 && getTimeLeft() < 841000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "There may be a heavy lag due to many users at stage 1 all at once. It won't be difficult, so please make sure not to fall down because of heavy lag."));
             } else if (getTimeLeft() > 869000 && getTimeLeft() < 871000) {
                 chr.getClient().announce(MaplePacketCreator.serverNotice(0, "[MapleStory Physical Fitness Test] consists of 4 stages, and if you happen to die during the game, you'll be eliminated from the game, so please be careful of that."));
             }
            } else {
             resetTimes();
            }
            }
           }, 5000, 29500);
       }
       // 14:30 [Notice][MapleStory Physical Fitness Test] consists of 4 stages, and if you happen to die during the game, you'll be eliminated from the game, so please be careful of that.
       // 14:00 [Notice]There may be a heavy lag due to many users at stage 1 all at once. It won't be difficult, so please make sure not to fall down because of heavy lag.
       // 13:00 [Notice]Everyone that clears [The Maple Physical Fitness Test] on time will be given an item, regardless of the order of finish, so just relax, take your time, and clear the 4 stages.
       // 11:40 [Notice]Please remember that if you die during the event, you'll be eliminated from the game. You still have plenty of time left, so either take a potion or recover HP first before moving on.
       // 11:00 [Notice]The 2nd stage offers monkeys throwing bananas. Please make sure to avoid them by moving along at just the right timing.
       // 10:00 [Notice]The most important thing you'll need to know to avoid the bananas thrown by the monkeys is *Timing* Timing is everything in this!
       // 8:20 [Notice]Please remember that if you die during the event, you'll be eliminated from the game. If you're running out of HP, either take a potion or recover HP first before moving on.
       // 6:00 [Notice]For those who have heavy lags, please make sure to move slowly to avoid falling all the way down because of lags.
       // 5:00 [Notice]The 3rd stage offers traps where you may see them, but you won't be able to step on them. Please be careful of them as you make your way up.
       // 4:00 [Notice]The 4th stage is the last one for [The Maple Physical Fitness Test]. Please don't give up at the last minute and try your best. The reward is waiting for you at the very top!
       // 1:40 [Notice]Alright, you don't have much time remaining. Please hurry up a little!
       // 0:10 [Notice]You have 10 sec left. Those of you unable to beat the game, we hope you beat it next time! Great job everyone!! See you later~
}
```

MapleCharacter script:

```
//EVENTS
private byte team = 0;
private MapleFitness fitness;
private MapleOla ola;
private long snowballattack;

public byte getTeam() {
    return team;
}

public void setTeam(int team) {
    this.team = (byte) team;
}

public MapleOla getOla() {
    return ola;
}

public void setOla(MapleOla ola) {
    this.ola = ola;
}

public MapleFitness getFitness() {
    return fitness;
}

public void setFitness(MapleFitness fit) {
    this.fitness = fit;
}

public long getLastSnowballAttack() {
    return snowballattack;
}

public void setLastSnowballAttack(long time) {
    this.snowballattack = time;
}
```

Comment: where do you create the private MapleFitness fitness; object? I don't see its construction anywhere in your code

Comment: Please paste the exception stack trace as text.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz MapleCharacter

Comment: you declare it in your MapleCharacter but where do you do the following - fitness = new MapleFitness()? I don't see that line

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz i dont have the following line fitness = new MapleFitness() 
This is the problem? if so where put that line

Comment: in your contrsutcor of the MapleCharacter class but i don't see a MapleCharacter constructor in the example code you provided

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz here the full code of MapleCharacter

https://codeshare.io/axJrRj

Comment: inside your getFitness function, check if fitness is null, and if it is, create the object and then return it

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz like this:



public MapleFitness getFitness() {
        if (getFitness() == null) {
        return getFitness();

Comment: did It and cant compile cause Public Void setFitness line get error : illegal of expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the MapleFitness is null and if it is, then create the object before returning like this

```
public MapleFitness getFitness() {

    if(fitness == null)
        fitness = new MapleFitness();

    return fitness;
}
```